# How to stop widget reloading Futter

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-listview

I am building an week planner app. I've used [buttons_tabbar](https://pub.dev/packages/buttons_tabbar) as tabbar.
It fetches the data from Firebase Realtime Database.

The problem is whenever I reopen a tab it recreate the widget and reload its data from Firebase which causes a bad user experience. I want to somehow stop this recreating of Widgets.

[image]

My code:

```
TabBarView(
              children: [
                AppList(day: "Monday"),
                AppList(day: "Tuesday"),
                AppList(day: "Wednesday"),
                AppList(day: "Thursday"),
                AppList(day: "Friday"),
                AppList(day: "Saturday"),
                AppList(day: "Sunday"),
              ],
            )
```

Function to load data from Firebase is calling on initState of AppList Widget.

AppList Widget:

```
List events = <Event>[];
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getList();
}


Future<void> getList() async {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final snapshot =
      await ref.child('users/${user?.uid}/events/${widget.day}').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    for (DataSnapshot i in snapshot.children) {
      Event event = Event(
        id: i.key.toString(),
        day: widget.day,
        title: i.child('title').value.toString(),
        info: i.child('info').value.toString(),
        color: i.child('color').value as int,
        starts: i.child('starts').value as int,
        ends: i.child('ends').value as int,
      );
      events.add(event);
    }
  }
setState(() {});
}

ListView.builder(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: events.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Event e = events[index];
            return EventCard(
              id: e.id,
              title: e.title,
              day: e.day,
              info: e.info,
              color: e.color,
              startTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.starts),
              endTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.ends),
            );
          },
        )
```

Comment: As far as I can see none of the code you shared loads anything from Firebase. Did you forget the actual API call that is getting repeated?

Comment: Yes, presuming your events list is fleshed out, there should be no fetching from an API on tabbar switches.  Where is events set up, and what is its scope and persistence?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the code for getting the data from firebase

Comment: @RandalSchwartz too, as he might know better than I do what's going on here. :)

Comment: Why are you calling setState?  Is this in your model, or in your view?  If view, it's in the wrong place.